# Prawn syntax into a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I would like to switch my pdf generation form the controller to the model. But I am not very comfortable with the syntax.

> My controller (is working) :

```
def generate_pdf
  value_1 = 1
  value_2 = 2
  pdf = FacturationPdf.new(@facturation, value_1, value_2)
      pdf.render_file "facturation.pdf"
      send_file filename, :filename => "facturation.pdf", :type => "application/pdf"
      redirect_back
end
```

> My model (now working)

```
def gen_my_pdf
  FacturationPdf.generate("facturation.pdf") do |pdf|
    pdf.value_1 pdf.value_1
    pdf.value_2 pdf.value_2
  end
end
```